# How to simulate an elastic force, using Hinge Joint ?

Tags: unity, physics

I've a bucket connected to a rope.

I would like that when a ball fall in my bucket , my bucket "bounce"down and up .. like it is connected to an elastic rope.

How can i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: So you solved the bucket collision problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into Spring Joint. I don't think the Hinge Join is appropriate to solve your issue.

[image]

Video Demo:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IpSi3Pg01kPa0mrAiemXcMs6tM--2QYb/view?usp=sharing

Unity3D documentation:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint.html

Comment: May I ask you the value you've used about spring/damper etc ?

Comment: I made a [unitypackage](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cu7SLnf7HUymigW7f0yJq4LGRC4GHuZ6/view?usp=sharing) I hope it will help.